# How to capture payment confirmation in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I need to insert some tags for affiliation in a magento website. The problem is, I can't find where the payment confirmation event is captured to redirect the user to success.phtml
Thanks

Comment: Hi Ali, you probably need to google more. This question is a bit too simple and open-ended. & since this is about monetizing, you might not get as much help. I personally stay out of the payment stuff...

Answer (score 0):

The order / payment place process is carried about by the saveOrderAction() action method in the Mage_Checkout_OnepageController controller class (in 'app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php').

Once the order is successful, the customer is redirected to the success page you mentioned, which is handled by the successAction() action method in Mage_Checkout_OnepageController.

Affiliate network tags should most likely be placed directly in 'success.phtml'.  You should have access to all the order data you need in that template file.  But if for some reason you need to do more work than is appropriate in a template file, you could handle the 'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action' event, thrown in successAction():

```
/**
 * Order success action
 */
public function successAction()
{
    $session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();
    if (!$session->getLastSuccessQuoteId()) {
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }

    $lastQuoteId = $session->getLastQuoteId();
    $lastOrderId = $session->getLastOrderId();
    $lastRecurringProfiles = $session->getLastRecurringProfileIds();
    if (!$lastQuoteId || (!$lastOrderId && empty($lastRecurringProfiles))) {
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }

    $session->clear();
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
    Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_onepage_controller_success_action', array('order_ids' => array($lastOrderId)));
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```